# Operations on selected items

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I want to have query like this:

```
SELECT 
  sum(data_parts.size) as size_sum,
  (size_sum/2.) as half_of_size_sum
FROM 
  data_parts
WHERE
  data_parts.some_id='1';
```

Of course it won't work, because there's no column named `size_sum`, so my question is:

Is there a way to use `size_sum` as a parameter in next select item?

Comment: use sub query concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than using a subquery containing your current query (see Davide's answer), I don't think there is a way to do that.

But you could always do:

```
SELECT 
  sum(data_parts.size) as size_sum,
  (sum(data_parts.size)/2.) as half_of_size_sum
FROM 
  data_parts
WHERE
  data_parts.id='1';
```

Postgres is smart enough to only get that sum once. Only if this query will be greatly expanded with more calculations being done on `size_sum` would I recommend the subquery approach. Not because it works better, but because it will be easier to read. But if the current calculation is all you need, don't bother with a subquery. It would actually be less easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

yes, a (somewhat) ugly way of making the query run there is...

```
SELECT 
     SIZE_SUM,
     SIZE_SUM/2 AS HALF_OF_SIZE_SUM
  FROM (
      SELECT 
         sum(data_parts.size) as size_sum) 
      FROM 
        data_parts
      WHERE
      data_parts.id='1') X;
```

But I don't think there is a way on postgre to do operations directly based on the previous select fields

Answer (score 0):

No, and too unnecesary to use subselects for this, simply use `SUM(data_parts.size)` again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I catch your point.
Do you want the code like this?

```
SELECT 
  sum(data_parts.size) as size_sum,
  (sum(data_parts.size)/2.) as half_of_size_sum
FROM 
  data_parts
WHERE
  data_parts.some_id='1';
```

Comment: Yes, but I thought there's a way to avoid duplications.